# get the text in the display with ncurses

Tags: c, ncurses, curses

Is there any way to get back the characters outputted into a variable on ncurses ?

let's say I do:

```
printw("test");
```

then I want to be able to:

```
somefunc(strbuffer);
printf("%s",strbuffer); // test
```

I need a function to get back all characters on the screen into a variable, scr_dump get's close but the output format is unreadable..

Comment: the answer is still correct and should be accepted :-)

Answer (score 11):

If you put stuff on the screen using curses functions (e.g. addch, mvaddch, addstr) you can use [`inchstr`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcurses/inchstr.html)) and related functions to read the characters from the screen (extracting them with AND'ing the returned value with [`A_CHARTEXT`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcurses/curses.h.html)).

However, if you use printf or any other non-curses method of puting text on the screen (including a system call to another program that uses curses) you will not be able to read the content of the screen.

Curses maintains the current screen contents internally and the inchstr functions use the internal representation of the screen to find the current contents.

Answer (score 3):

There are two sets of functions for retrieving data from the screen.  If your `printw` uses only (as in the question) text which is represented as an 8-bit encoding (ASCII, POSIX, ISO-8859-1), then `inch` and `inchstr` work:

- [**`inch`**](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_inch.3x.html) retrieves a single cell along with its attributes
- [`inchstr`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_inchstr.3x.html) retrieves multiple cells along with their attributes

or more simply using [**`instr`**](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_instr.3x.html) and its variations.  These functions return the data without additional need for masking the attributes from the characters.

However, if the data uses a multibyte encoding (such as UTF-8), then you must use a different interface for retrieving the characters.  These are the equivalents of `inch` and `inchstr`:

- [**`in_wch`**,  etc. - extract a complex character and
     rendition from a window](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_in_wch.3x.html)
- [**`in_wchstr`**, etc. - get an array of complex
     characters and renditions from a curses window](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_in_wchstr.3x.html)

A *complex character* is a structure, which X/Open Curses treats as opaque.  You must use [`getcchar`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_getcchar.3x.html#h3-getcchar) to extract data (such as a *wide-character* string) from each cell's data.

A (little) more simply, you can read the *wide-character* string information from a window:

- [**`inwstr`**,  etc. - get a string of **`wchar_t`** characters from a curses window](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_inwstr.3x.html)
- there is no single-character form; you must retrieve data as a one-character string.

In summary, while your application can put data as an array of **`char`** (or individual `chtype` values), in a UTF-8 environment it must retrieve it as *complex characters* or *wide-characters*.  If you happen to be using Linux, you can generally treat `wchar_t` as Unicode values.  Given data as an array of `wchar_t` values, you would use other (non-curses) functions to obtain a multibyte (UTF-8) string.

Since the question said **ncurses** rather than simply **curses**, it's appropriate to point out that applications using ncurses can differ from X/Open Curses in the way they put data on the screen (which can affect your expectations about retrieving it).  In ncurses, `addch` (and similar **`char`**-oriented functions) will handle bytes in a multi-byte string such as UTF-8, storing the result as wide-characters.  None of the other X/Open Curses implementations to date do this.  The others treat those bytes as independent, and may represent them as invalid wide-characters.

By the way, since the question was asked in 2010, ncurses' [`scr_dump` format](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/scr_dump.5.html) has been extended, making it "readable".