# getting input from specific position of console

Tags: c, io, console

I want to get input from special position of console. I called **my** `gotoxy` function to go to the specific position, then called `gets` or `scanf` to get input from that position.But the cursor waits for user input and do not input previous text the user has input. What is wrong with my code?
This is my code:

```
//suppose we are in position (0,0)
printf("%s","Hello world!\n");
//now we are in position (0,1)
gotoxy(0,0);
scanf("%s",string);//or gets(string)
```

Now string should be `"Hello world!"` but it waits for user input.

My gotoxy:

```
void gotoxy(int x , int y){
COORD newPosition={x,y};
SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),newPosition);
}
```

Comment: Which header includes `gotoxy` function?

Comment: Please post the source to `gotoxy()`, and why you think it's failing.

Comment: @Dogbert: if you want your own `gotoxy()` without running on Windows, you can use this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9782318/4323 - but it doesn't change the answer to the question.

Comment: Never,Never use `gets`. Being dangerous,it has been removed from newer C standards.

Comment: As I said I use gets or **scanf**.

Comment: @M.K: the point is you should use `fgets` or `scanf`, not `gets` or `scanf`.  Pretend `gets` never existed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`gotoxy()` will change the position of the cursor for future output operations, but this does not mean you can read from the screen.

`scanf()` is a standard function which reads from `stdin`, e.g. the keyboard.  There is no way to use it to read characters previously printed on the screen.  To do that, it would be much easier for you to simply maintain your own buffer of what characters you've written to the screen, and read from that buffer when needed.

Comment: I am a beginner,so ask this question:what is buffer?

Comment: A buffer is usually an array of something in memory, in this case a 2D representation of the screen that you can write characters into to retrieve them later.

Comment: another question:Is there a simple way so that when console changes,our buffer changes contemporaneously?

Comment: I'm not sure.  On *nix you could use ncurses and this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3089190/4323 but since you're on Windows I don't know what the equivalent is.