# Python Curses, reading wide character's attribute from screen

Tags: python, python-curses, widechar

The problem I'm trying to solve is to get a couple `ch`,`att` representing the character and the associated attribute currently displayed at some given position.

Now, when the displayed character is not a wide one (i.e. an ASCII character), the method `.inch` does the job up to masking correctly the results. The issue comes when the displayed character is wide. More precisely I know how to get the given character through `.instr`, however this function does not return any information about the attribute.

Since, as far as I know, there is no specific function to get the attribute alone, my first attempt was to use `.inch`, drop the 8 less significant bit and interpret the result as the attribute. This seemed to work to some extent but double checking I realized that reading greek letters (`u"u\03b1"` for instance) with no attribute in this way returns `att = 11.0000.0000` instead of `0`. Is there a better way to approach the problem?

EDIT, a minimal example for Python3

```
import curses

def bin(x):
    out = ''
    while x > 0:
        out = str(x % 2) + out
        x = x // 2

    return out

def main(s):
    s.addstr(1, 1, u'\u03b1')
    s.refresh()

    chratt = s.inch(1, 1)

    att = chratt & 0xFF00

    s.addstr(2, 1, bin(att))
    s.refresh()

    while True:
        pass

curses.wrapper(main)
```

Comment: It will be better if you could add some code snippet.

Comment: @nngeek, Snippet added

Comment: @JayTuma what do you mean by "wide"?

Comment: @wowkin2 By wide character i mean one that in the utf-8 encoding is not represented by one byte (non-ASCII symbols to be more clear)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In curses, inch and instr is only for ascii characters as you suspected. "complex" or "wide" characters like characters from utf-8 have another system, as explained [here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47326454/13089524) by one of the ncurses creators.

However, onto the bad news. They aren't implemented in python curses (yet). A pull request was submitted [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/17825) and it is very close to merging (90%), so if you really need it then why not go contribute yourself?

And if that isn't an option, then you could try to store every change you make to your screen in a variable and then pull the wide characters from there.